# Denoising an Image using ImageJ Macros

Tags: image-processing, noise, imagej

I would like to ask how to denoise this image using ImageJ macros.

[image: the image to be denoised]

I know it's like coding in C but i want to know what is the algorithm that i can use to denoise this picture.

Comment: I do not see any effort from your side in trying to solve the problem for yourself. Please describe [what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't make it clear what you want to use the "cleaned" image for - but if you are doing OCR or similar, I would start by converting the image to binary, then use the morphological operations to clean it up.

For example, here is your image after : Binarisation -> Open - Close :

[image: picture]

Comment: this is our exercise in our image processing class. Our instructor put noise on the original image using the RandomJ noise models and he wants us to perform image restoration filters to take out the noise. There are many RandomJ noise models that he used like Gaussian,binomial,gamma etc. and he wants us to take these noise away using ImageJ Macro Language.